# Why is my foreach faster than my for loop?

Tags: c#, performance, loops

```
int[] testArray = new int[200000000];

Stopwatch st2 = new Stopwatch();
st2.Start();

for (var j = 0; j < testArray.Length; j++)
{

}

st2.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Total milliseconds - FOR LOOP: {0}", st2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);



Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
st.Start();

foreach (var arr in testArray)
{

}

st.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Total milliseconds - FOREACH LOOP: {0}", st.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Results:

> for: 0,7046522 seconds
>   foreach: 0,05508682 seconds

Why is my foreach faster? I thought that my for loop would be faster than the foreach

Comment: I get a result of about 0.6 secs for the foreach - not much different from the for-result (0.7 secs)

Comment: I can't replicate these results. I get `Total milliseconds - FOR LOOP: 0.1187888
Total milliseconds - FOREACH LOOP: 0.2583282` in a release build.

Comment: Read how to properly benchmark JITed code. This is not a valid benchmark.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I get very similar results to you.

Comment: put some operation inside both loop, to have a more sensible test

Comment: You're not doing anything inside the loop, so it might be just a compiler optimization. If I add a statement inside each loop, I get results like 0.18 for the for-loop and 0.95 for the foreach-loop.

Comment: Simply by running this with optimizations, you'll avoid the bounds check on each iteration of the `for` loop, and you'll see it executing faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is explained in detailed in this [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach). it says that

> In micro-benchmarking, introducing extra local variables with
>   foreach-loops can impact performance. However, if those local
>   variables are reused several times in the loop body, they can lead to
>   a performance improvement.
>
> Thus: The for-loop is faster than the foreach-loop if the array must
>   only be accessed once per iteration.

You can realize this by including some operations in the loop and runs it again.